# how to get the version of mysql without running anything relate to mysql itself?

Tags: mysql, system-administration

there are many ways to retrieve version of mysql, such as :

running a SQL statements in the server, `SELECT VERSION();`

or invoke the mysql binary itself providing '-v' as argument:
`mysql --version`

but for some reason (stability and security concern) I am not at the privilege of utilizing these methods. I wonder where these version information are stored, so I can extract them just by reading the file?

Comment: try the `strings` command...

Comment: @ebyrob can you elaborate? I tried `strings` on some of those executables like mysqld, but there are too much noise.

Comment: also try `grep` and make sure you've learned how to "pipe" commands together.  (Or at least how to redirect `stdout` to a file)  PS - this should probably be on serverfault or even superuser, not stack overflow as it probably isn't a programming question.  Of course, if your requirements turn out difficult enough I suppose it could be.  (ie: no read access, but doesn't seem the case.  you don't have to work outside that small a box)

Comment: @ebyrob definitely I have piped that through grep, but there is a nother problem, what pattern are you grepping apart from just grepping the version pattern?, I would have expected a more precise prefix or suffix for version information.

Comment: I don't have strings on windows... at the moment.  I suspect that if I thought I knew the version number, or part of it, I would just search for `5.7.` or `8.0.` or something like that.  Once I had "eyeballed" a match, I would tailor future searches based on that.  It also occurs, that something like telnet could connect to un-encrypted SQL without any SQL libraries and ask for server variables...  If it were encrypted, I'm not sure whether SSH could be configured to do similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the version of the installed `mysql-server` package.

For Red Hat based systems use:

```
rpm -qa | grep mysql
```

For Debian based systems use:

```
apt list mysql-server
```

Answer (score 0):

if the log-file is readable for you:

```
grep Version /var/log/mysqld.log
```

Comment: is it stable enough to be used against most versions?